# Is there a predefined mathematical function for $ f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned} &x &&: x < n\\ &x - n &&: x \ge n \end{aligned} \right.$

Tags: functions, piecewise-continuity

if n is a constant, is there a predefined/shorter mathematical function that can replace this function :
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&x &&: x < n\\
&x - n &&: x \ge n
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

where x >= 0 and x < 2n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this function from the Heaviside step:

$$f(x):= x-nH(x-n).$$

Make sure to use the convention $H(0):=1.$

Comment: that's a very nice function, as I understand, it converts the "if" side of the function to either 0 or 1, is that correct?

Comment: @bigworld12: that's it. More deeply, it is used to represent "causal" phenomena, i.e. that can not happen before time $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is discontinuous if $n\neq0$, and any reasonable operations with continuous functions give again something continuous. So if you don't want a definition by cases you'll have to either use a discontinuous function at some point, or a complicated expression that won't be shorter than what you have. (e.g. something with $\arctan$ and floor.)

Answer (score -1):

actually there IS a function that can do the same, which is the modulus

the above function is the same as

x mod n

although it isn't true for all values of x, it's what I have been looking for

Comment: You may want to include a definition of mod you are using here. It certainly isn't the same as this one: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Modulo_Operation

Comment: I should limit my original question to x > 0 and x < 2n